# What is the difference between Path and ClassPath in Java?

Tags: java, path, classpath

Why do we need Path and ClassPath?
When using IDE's like eclipse we still need to add path ?

Comment: You can find many links in google like : http://java67.blogspot.in/2012/08/what-is-path-and-classpath-in-java-difference.html , http://www.tutorial4us.com/java/difference-between-path-and-classpath etc

Answer (score 9):

We don't need to set **PATH** and **CLASSPATH** to compile and run java program while using IDE like **Eclipse**.
These environment variables are required to **compile** and **run** java program using **CMD**.
**Example-:** Here is the screen shot of console to understand **PATH** and **CLASSPATH** quickly

[image]

**Explanation-:** 
**Compiling the program-**
I have java program file `Demo.java` stored at location `D:\Programs\Classes`. Now I pointed location to `D:\Programs\Classes` in CMD and executed **javac Demo.java** command. System will understand `javac` with the help of **PATH** variable. Java program `Demo.java` is complied successfully because **PATH** is set correctly to `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

**Running the program (class file)-**
Since class file has been generated at the same location `D:\Programs\Classes`, so we can run this class file by typing command **java Demo** as displayed in second line in the screenshot. Now system will find the class file with the help of **CLASSPATH** since my **CLASSPATH** variable has `D:\Programs\Classes` path.

**It's not required to point class file location in CMD to run it.** System will understand **java** command with the help of **PATH** variable and find that class using **CLASSPATH** variable to run it.

Answer (score 8):

path is a mediator between developer and operating system to inform binary file path 
where as Classpath is a mediator between developer and compiler to inform the library file path those are used in our source code

Answer (score 5):

The path points to the location of the jre i.e. the java binary files such as the jvm and necessary libraries. The classpath points to the classes you developed so that the jvm can find them and load them when you run your product.

So essentially you need the path to find java so it can then find your classes and run them from the classpath

Answer (score 3):

let us clear the difference in points:

**PATH**

a) An environment variable which is used by the
operating system to find the executables.

b) PATH is nothing but setting up an
environment for operating system. Operating
System will look in this PATH for executables.

c) Refers to the system

**CLASSPATH**

a) An environment variable which is used by the
Java compiler to find the path, of classes i.e in
J2EE we give the path of jar files.

b) Classpath is nothing but setting up the
environment for Java. Java will use to find
compiled classes.

c) Refers to the Developing Enviornment.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between PATH and CLASSPATH is that  PATH is an environment variable which is used to locate JDK binaries like "java" or "javac" command used to run java program and compile java source file. On the other hand, CLASSPATH, an environment variable is used by System or Application ClassLoader to locate and load compile Java bytecodes stored in the .class file.

For more info: http://www.java67.com/2012/08/what-is-path-and-classpath-in-java-difference.html

Answer (score 1):

path : it is location of bin files(binary executable files)
example- java.exe,javac.exe

classPath: it is location of your .class file(which is created after compile your java source file)

Answer (score 1):

Path and Classpath both are operating system level environment variales. Path is used define where the system can find the executables(.exe) files and classpath is used to specify the location .class files.

Answer (score 0):

PATH is the environment variable where we specify the locations of binaries.

Example: We add bin directory path of JDK or JRE, so that any binaries under the directory can be accessed directly without specifying absolute path.


CLASSPATH is the path for Java application where the classes you compiled will be available.

Answer (score 0):

[Difference between path and classpath](http://www.tutorial4us.com/java/difference-between-path-and-classpath)

Difference between path and classpath in Java

path is set for use java tool in your java program like java, javac, javap.
javac are used for compile the code. and classpath are used for use predefined class in
your program for example use scanner class in your program for this you need to set classpath.

http://www.tutorial4us.com/java/difference-between-path-and-classpath